# Netezza jpa update not called

Tags: jpa, netezza

Working with netezza through jpa. Trying to update row in a simple table, but nothing happens in database. Updating using merge command.
Select works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: errm, look at the log

Comment: Neil Stockton, there is no update statement in log output (login level set) even it should be one. It somehow related to the netezza and jpa combination. Maybe anyone has such experience and know what should I check?

Comment: so what JPA transaction is running ? and what happens when you FLUSH?

Comment: also I've no idea what a "login level set" is wrt the log. The JPA implementation has a log, all of them do. That is what needs looking at, not some "netezza" log

Comment: As I already mentioned I use merge command on my entityManager. With other databases (that could be specified to jpa engine explicitly  like MySql or Oracle) I had experience with, this was enough. With netezza log contains all the same info about transactions, no errors that it couldn't form update. Nothing. It even returns result like it was successful update, but when I check DB information is still the same. Do you think it is related to transactions management differences?

Comment: if you do some "merge" on an EntityManager then something would be logged. And you don't say which JPA implementation is used - I'm assuming EclipseLink, for that DB. The ONLY way that something doesn't go to the DB is where you have optimistic txns and things are delayed til commit (or if you never commit then forgotten)

Comment: I also use EclipseLink. The only info from log is that it started and ended transaction and selected updated entity. Should I explicitly commit after calling "merge" on EntityManager or it is the Netezza DB settings that should be changed? Maybe you could share your eclipselink config?